# which one is more important : optimize database size or make less process

Tags: database, laravel, optimization

in my laravel project i have many users who have ads and each ad have some keywords : users->ads->keywords (with 3 tables in database)

state 1 : make this with just 2 relation between users/ads and ads/keywords

in this case when i want to access all keywords of a user i should first get that user ads collection and then use a foreach to get all keywords of that user.

state 2 : make a direct relation between keywords/users
in this state

i can get the user keywords directly from database with less process,but the bad thing is that i should have one more field (user_id) in my keywords table.

my question is which one of these two ways are more optimize in large scale.
is having one more field in database with one less foreach better?

thanks friends.

Comment: each keyword belongs to only one user or maybe more

Answer (score 0):

**1 solution.** If each `user` has many `ads` and `ads` has many `keywords` it is bad add `user_id and 'ad_id'` in `keywords` table because it must be has duplicate keywords.
The right way for does not have duplicate record you must be make 4 table `users, ads, keywords, ad_keyword` tables `ad_keyword` is join table. 
For this case your code must be similar this

```
   $userId = 1; 
   $ads = Ad::where('user_id', $userId)->get(['user_id]);
   $adIds = $ads->pluck('user_id')->all();
   $keywords = Ad::with('keywords')->whereIn('id', $adIds)->get();
```

**2 solution.** 
You must be make 5 table `users, ads, keywords, ad_keyword, keyword_user` tables `ad_keyword, 'keyword_user` is join table, (but it is not correspond database normalizaation but helpful for big db). 
For this case your code must be similar this

```
   $userId = 1; 
   $keywords = User::with('keywords')->where('id', $user)->get();
```

Comment: Alphabetical naming convention of pivot table. can you sand any post related this @Tpojka

Comment: Sure. Straight from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the concept of a "[join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)".

The relational database model is designed specifically to separate data into logical entities which are associated via foreign keys. Laravel is a thin layer on top of this relational model.

Most of the time, it's *much* better to build a clean relational model first, and optimize that as far as you possibly can to get the performance you need, instead of optimizing for speed from the beginning. In your case, I'd expect the "clean" version (your option 1, but with a join rather than for-each) to be just as fast as your "dirty" version (option 2; it's dirty because you are duplicating information).